# How to replace duplicate rows in pandas groupby with the more recent record

Tags: python, pandas

Good Morning.

Let's say I have a table that looks like the following:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Selection Criteria (Date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2022-05 |
| A | B | 2022-06 |
| C | D | 2022-05 |
| C | D | 2022-06 |
| E | F | 2022-05 |

I'd like to group this table by column_1 and column_2,

> (i.e. df.groupby['column 1','column 2])

and then drop the duplicate rows that have the older date. Running this statement against the table above would yield:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Selection Criteria (Date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2022-06 |
| C | D | 2022-06 |
| E | F | 2022-05 |

In general Column 1 and 2 make up the primary key of the table, and the selection criteria column is only included for the selection of records based on time.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: do you want to drop the oldest date or to keep the newest one? (in other words, what should happen if you have 3 dates in a group?)

Comment: Sorry about not being clear, the intent is to keep only the most recent date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df.sort_values('Selection Criteria(Date)').groupby(['Column 1', 'Column 2'], as_index=False).last()
```

print(df):

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Selection Criteria(Date)
0        A        B                  2022-06
1        C        D                  2022-06
2        E        F                  2022-05
```

Or [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) on datetime

```
df['Selection Criteria(Date)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Selection Criteria(Date)'])
df.groupby(['Column 1', 'Column 2'], as_index=False).max()
```

print(df):

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Selection Criteria(Date)
0        A        B               2022-06-01
1        C        D               2022-06-01
2        E        F               2022-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby(['column 1','column 2']).tail(1)
```

you can try this